# Dandelion Datatable + Thymeleaf + Pagination Issue

Tags: datatables, thymeleaf, dandelion

I am trying to use dandelion datatable paging with thymeleaf. I am following 
this [link](http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/features/basics/paging.html) article. I am using 0.2.14 version. When I try to use

> dt:paginationtype="four_button" it throws following exception.

It gives me following error

```
2013-08-07 16:26:59,655 ERROR [org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine] - <[THYMELEAF][http-bio-8080-exec-9] Exception processing template "department/departmentList": 
Could not parse as expression: "four_button"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try wrapping "four_button" with single quotes as follows:

```
dt:paginationtype="'four_button'"
```

Note that in the upcoming v0.9.0, the single quotes won't be necessary any longer.

Comment: This does not work for dt:paginationtype="two_button", with or without single quotes. Gives a javascript error in Firebug: TypeError: plugin is undefined plugin.fnInit( settings, node, redraw );

Comment: Please fill an issue (with the version used): https://github.com/dandelion/dandelion-datatables/issues Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37748231/dandelion-datatables-spring-mvc-pagination-disables-if-pipelining-is-false I have similar issue