# Dandelion Datatables + Spring mvc pagination disables if pipelining is false

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, datatable, pagination, dandelion

I am trying to use datatables in one of my project. If I am removing `pipelining="true" pipesize="3"` then pagination is not coming and if I do so it fetches all data in JSON Format.

```
<datatables:table id="lonlatTable" url="getLatLonList" serverSide="true" pipelining="true" pipeSize="3" row="latlon" rowIdBase="id" rowIdPrefix="latlon_" displayLength="10" lengthMenu="10,15,25,50,100,200,500,700,1000" jqueryUI="true"
filterable="true" sortable="true" processing="true" scrollX="true"  autoWidth="true" pageable="true" paginationType="full_numbers" stateSave="false" deferRender="true"   >
```

What should I do as I am using **Dandelion 0.10.0**.

I have upgeaded to 1.1.0 but still no luck. I have found that it is not generating `pipelining.js.`

[image: error]

In older version of dandelion pagination was working without any problem.

**Edit:**

Adding

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/dandelion/**" location="/dandelion/" />
```

in dispatcher it solved pipelining problem but  now it fails with

> TypeError: $.fn.dataTable.Api is undefined

Please provide solution because project is delaying.

Comment: Should I jump to angulr datatables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/dandelion/**" location="/dandelion/" />
```

in dispatcher it solved pipelining problem